# Do i NEED to switch storage mode in BIOS from RAID to AHCI to install Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I'm a purely windows user who decided to make the jump to Ubuntu due to the nature of my work. And god, is it pure trouble. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a windows 10 home laptop.

First I needed to trawl through the internet to find out I had to manually rename the mmx64.efi file or my usb wouldnt even boot.

Now, a new problem which I have no idea how to even tackle: the storage partition I created for my m.2 NVME SSD in Windows is never recognised by the Ubuntu loaded on the USB.

Online searches have thrown up very conflicting suggestions:

1) Change storage type in BIOS from RAID(Acer preconfigured my laptop to RAID) to AHCI

2) BUT hey! AHCI is SATA-based so its speculated that:
    a) I lose NVME speeds
    b) Windows boots only based on the previous known storage config which is RAID so AHCI essentially bricks Windows (defeating the purpose of dualboot LOL)

I'm essentially at my wits end here, please help :(

Only usable link i found is this: [Ubuntu installer won't recognize NVMe SSD - Lenovo Yoga 720 15-IKB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024917/ubuntu-installer-wont-recognize-nvme-ssd-lenovo-yoga-720-15-ikb)

Just an edit for the answer below:

Despite the optimism which I do appreciate, both your suggestions caused my windows 10 to brick, as expected. So now once again, Ubuntu's f*king me over LOL

Comment: So far, everything you have described seems like unfortunate choices by the hardware vendor that make installation (perhaps unintentionally) more difficult than it needs to be. Most folks have much easier experiences.

Comment: You have to install the Windows AHCI driver before you change. Or reset to RAID on and install Windows driver. Intel Optane - See Intel response that no performance difference between RAID & AHCI.
https://communities.intel.com/thread/121155 What brand/model system? What video card chip? Most systems also require UEFI update & SSD firmware update, which you need even if just Windows. If Acer, you also have to set "trust" : http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 4):

> Do i NEED to switch storage mode in BIOS from RAID to AHCI to install Ubuntu?

Yes. Unless you can find a RAID driver for your hardware that supports Linux(/Ubuntu).

> Online searches have thrown up very conflicting suggestions:

Not to me: you use AHCI for all operating systems.

> 2) BUT hey! AHCI is SATA-based so its speculated that:
>
> a) I lose NVME speeds

Does not seem a problem to me: It works. Slower speed can be an inconvenience sure but not a problem that stops you from using Ubuntu or using a dual boot.

The problem is hardware related: vendors do not supply the drivers we need. So when you want to use more than one operating system you can only use methods all the operating systems in use support. In this case both accept AHCI and 1 does not support RAID.

> b) Windows boots only based on the previous known storage config which is RAID so AHCI essentially bricks Windows (defeating the purpose of dualboot LOL)

No. You can set AHCI without re-installing. See for instance [Install dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 and RAID on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on) It lists 2 possible methods.

Comment: Tried 1). Bricked my computer and I had to do a system restore. Tried 2) ALSO bricked Windows 10. I'm not trying to be negative, but its fucking 2019. Is ubuntu this non-user-friendly, convoluted garbage that's basically not compatible with anything? Win10 works right out of the box, MacOS works right out of the box. And yet Ubuntu insists on dragging me through shit on literally every aspect of my laptop's hardware

Comment: Feel free to stick with windows. We lack support from hardware vendors. Either they actually do not care or accept kickbacks from microsoft and apple.